# Web browser does not interpret the image passed via an unsigned char array

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, network-programming, packet-capture

What I am trying to do basically is to capture the HTTP GET request of the browser via a socket and send that request to the Internet, then capture the reply and send it back to the browser. When the transfer consist only of text, every thing works perfectly. But when downloading an image. browser gives the error "cant display the image because it contains errors". any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include "cc352.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int                 listenfd, connfd,weblin,webcon,webwrite,n,x,y,w,w1;
socklen_t           len,wlen;
struct sockaddr_in  servaddr, cliaddr , webservad , webcliad;
unsigned char       buff[3072] , buff2[3072] ,ext[5] ,wbuff[100000];
time_t              ticks;
int                 yes = 1;
const char          *ptr;


if ( (listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ){
    fprintf(stderr, "socket creation failed\n");
    exit (1);
     }

bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

if (inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1", &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0){
    printf("inet_pton error for %s", argv[1]);
    return 1;
     }
servaddr.sin_port        = htons(4619); 

if ( (bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "bind failed\n");
    exit (1);
    fprintf(stdout, "bindd completed\n");
     }


if ( (weblin = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ){
    fprintf(stderr, "socket creation failed\n");
    exit (1);
     }
printf("weblin socket created \n");

bzero(&webservad, sizeof(webservad));
webservad.sin_family      = AF_INET;
webservad.sin_port        = htons(80); 

if (inet_pton(AF_INET,"208.80.152.211", &webservad.sin_addr) <= 0){
    printf("inet_pton error for %s", argv[1]);
    return 1;
     }


if (connect(weblin, (SA *) &webservad, sizeof(webservad)) < 0) {
    printf("weblin connect error");
    return 1; 
     }
printf("weblin connected \n");


if ( listen(listenfd, LISTENQ) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "listen failed\n");
    exit (1);
    fprintf(stderr, "listning\n");
     }


    len = sizeof(cliaddr);
    if ( (connfd = accept(listenfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &len)) < 0 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "accept failed\n");
    exit (1);
     }
fprintf(stdout, "Connection accepted\n");


        int d=0;

           read(connfd,&buff, 3071); // Reads GET request from browser save it to array buff
           unsigned char bron[strlen(buff)];

           for(d=0 ; d<=sizeof(bron) ; d++){
           bron[d]=buff[d];
           }
           write(weblin,bron, sizeof(bron)); // Send the data to Internet
           printf("%s \n",bron);


           while(d=read(weblin,&wbuff, 100000)>0){ //Reads the reply from Internet and save it to wbuff
           unsigned char wron[strlen(wbuff)];

           for(d=0 ; d<=sizeof(wron) ; d++ ){
            wron[d]=wbuff[d];
            }
           write(connfd,wbuff,strlen(wbuff)); //Writes the reply to the browser
           printf("%s \n",wron);
    }


 close(connfd);
 close(listenfd);
 close(weblin);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug this?  For instance, taking a look at how this handles images?   (i.e., are the bytes *identical*?)

Answer (score 5):

`strlen` is meant for C strings, that are `0` terminated. `0` is perfectly valid in the middle of a binary image file. So you're probably not sending as much data as you got. (Or even *more* data than you got, possibly even more than what your buffer is supposed to hold, if the image happens *not* to contain a `0`.)

Never do anything with the buffer you've passed to `read` if you don't check that the `read` call was successful. You *need* to use `read`'s return value because that's the only thing that tells you how much data you got.

You're assuming that you'll read the whole request in a single `read` call. Nothing guarantees that.

(I don't understand what you're trying to do with `wron`, and `bron` in un-necessary in your code. And there's a `memcpy` function. Use it rather than rolling your own.)

(And you should be checking the return code of all your `write` calls.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go through your code in it's entirety. But (one of) the problem is surely with your treatment of buffers as string buffers(That is `NULL` terminated buffers). Specially the usage of `strlen()` to find size of buffers.

For example this line (at the end of your code):

```
write(connfd,wbuff,strlen(wbuff))
```

This will fail for any payload, which does not contain plain-text data, as is the case with images.